# How to relaunch the closed app in Robotium?

Tags: android, robotium

I started to automate my Android app. It has a *"Terms & conditions"* screen. In that, if I click on *"decline"*, my app will be closed.

How can I relaunch or restart my app within the same process?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
// assuming this method is in a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class
public void test_yourTest() {

    // do your testing

    Solo.sleep(1000);

    // killing all your Activities manually if it doesn't by itself anyway
    Solo.finishOpenedActivities();

    // relaunch your app by calling the same Activity as in the constructor
    // of your ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
    this.launchActivity(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, YourStartActivity.class, null);

    Solo.sleep(1000);

    // do your testing
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you want to, head over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096491/lifecycle-testing-with-robotium-killing-and-restarting-activity/30099143#30099143 and post your answer there.