# how to restart killed android application in testing with robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am testing an apk using robotium. In this app, I have a button which kills the app process and relaunches it. I want to test this scenario using robotium.
When I click on the button through robotium, app is killed as expected but I cannot see that- it relaunches.

Comment: What do you think about solution I posted in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644288/how-to-relaunch-the-closed-app-in-robotium/17744154#17744154

Comment: @FlavioCapaccio: if you want to, head over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096491/lifecycle-testing-with-robotium-killing-and-restarting-activity/30099143#30099143 and post your answer there

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via robotium, Instrumentation tests live in the same process as your application (you can see this if you look at logcat) this means that when you kill your applications process the tests die along with it.